# Add table Twitter Bootstrap in Grails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails

I have this code built with Twitter Boostrap and Grails that works perfectly: I can show a table, I can search the elements of the table, I can show 10, 25 elements (if I write all the elements), and all work well. When I'm trying to add the code in the table (CODE B), the information display ok in the table, but I can't search the elements of the table and always I show all the elements, Don't work the label to show only 10, for example.

CODE A

```
<!-- /.row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                DataTables Advanced Tables
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Sku</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Trident</td>
                                <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
                                <td>Win 95+</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gecko</td>
                                <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
                                <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-responsive -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

CODE B

```
<!-- /.row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                DataTables Advanced Tables
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Sku</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <g:each in="${allProducts}" var="thisProduct">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>${thisProduct.name}</td>
                            <td>${thisProduct.sku}</td>
                            <td>${thisProduct.price}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </g:each>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-responsive -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: what do you mean by "search"? `Ctrl+F` in browser?

Comment: No, the table have a label where you can search some element in the own table. Look this link. The table code is from here.... http://datatables.net/examples/styling/display.html My problem is where I add the groovy code. Before works perfect, same that in the link that I give you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your each tag is misplaced, you should not repeat the tbody element.

Try the following code, I moved the  tag inside tbody.

```
<!-- /.row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        DataTables Advanced Tables
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Sku</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                  <tbody>
                                   <g:each in="${allProducts}" var="thisProduct">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>${thisProduct.name}</td>
                                        <td>${thisProduct.sku}</td>
                                        <td>${thisProduct.price}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                   </g:each>
                                  </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
```